# python readline from big text file

Tags: python-2.7

When I run this:

```
import os.path
import pyproj
srcProj = pyproj.Proj(proj='longlat', ellps='GRS80', datum='NAD83')
dstProj = pyproj.Proj(proj='longlat', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
f = file(os.path.join("DISTAL-data", "countries.txt"), "r")
heading = f.readline() # Ignore field names.
with open('C:\Python27\DISTAL-data\geonames_20160222\countries.txt', 'r') as f:         
  for line in f.readlines():
    parts = line.rstrip().split("|")
    featureName = parts[1]
    featureClass = parts[2]
    lat = float(parts[9])
    long = float(parts[10])
    if featureClass == "Populated Place":
      long,lat = pyproj.transform(srcProj, dstProj, long, lat)
  f.close()
```

I get this error:

> File "C:\Python27\importing world datacountriesfromNAD83 toWGS84.py",
>   line 13, in  for line in f.readlines() : MemoryError.

I have downloaded countries file from http://geonames.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.html as entire country file dataset.

Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 2):

readlines() for large files creates a large structure in memory, you can try using:

```
f = open('somefilename','r')
for line in f:
    dosomthing()
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer given by Yael is helpful, I would like to improve it. A Good way to read a file or large file

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print f
```

I like to use 'with' statement which ensure file will be properly closed.